# Google Map intergrate with Website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I use my map tool in google map to mark many destination in the map then I shared it as public and embbed it. There are many tabs but I raised only two for example one is Cambodia and another is China. I want to put the two maps follow by the country but in Cambodia tab the map works fine. Anyway when I view on the second tab it covers by the grey color with a small map. [Here is my website](http://su4star.com.kh/web/)

Here is the html code.

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#hot-hotel-popular" data-toggle="tab">Cambodia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#china" data-toggle="tab">China</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="hot-hotel-popular">
        <div class="row">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zgWkkp0_22Oc.kyb8oUGt7phc" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="china">
        <div class="row">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zgWkkp0_22Oc.kkk4nijv40pM" width="640" height="480" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first tab works fine but the second tab it shows only only small point and most of the other area covers by the grey color.

Please help me!!!!

Comment: What if you made the second map with the same attributes as the first one, i.e. `width="100%" height="500px"`

Comment: What does the css required for the tabs look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  ([fiddle with the posted HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/cuza29k9/))

Answer (score 0):

This should work, obviously:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#hot-hotel-popular" data-toggle="tab">Cambodia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#china" data-toggle="tab">China</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="hot-hotel-popular">
        <div class="row">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zgWkkp0_22Oc.kyb8oUGt7phc" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="china">
        <div class="row">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zgWkkp0_22Oc.kkk4nijv40pM" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If this doesn't work, you'll have to share more code to understand the issue.